# How to avoid creating new row in table after javaScript call?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm building a laravel application where I want to show if there is any update data in database after two seconds.So in this scenario I have given the table a 'id' and then I have laod the table after certain time interval. But the problem is after every javascript call it creates an empty row in table even if the table retrieve the value also. How do I avoid the problem..any suggestion please?

```
<div class="container">
            <h3> List Of Courses </h3></br>

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" id="example">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Serial No</td>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td>Description</td>                    
                <td>Action</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php $i=1; ?>
            @foreach($items as $row)

                <tr>
                    <td>{{$i}}</td>
                <td class="title" data-id1="{{$row->id}}" contenteditable>{{$row->title}}</td>  
                <td class="description" data-id2="{{$row->id}}" contenteditable>{{$row->description}}</td>  


                <td>    
                        <button type="button" onclick="deleteItem({{ $row->id }})" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>                   
                </td>

                </tr>

            <?php $i++; ?>

            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
```

Here is the javascript I have to use to load the table after 3 seconds:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setInterval(function() {
    $("#example").load("list #example");                                
  }, 30000);
</script>
```

Comment: How do you render each row?

Comment: using foreach loop ..

Comment: Can you post your whole code?

Comment: If the table is being rendered on server side, why do you need that interval at all?

Comment: @User57 .load() is Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element you have to pass url and elment refer here
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Nope I tried to fetch it but not getting anything ..@ShakirAhamed

Answer (score 1):

You need to give `load` a callback and check if you returned any data.
Without knowing the return data structure my best guess would be

```
$("#example").load("list #example", function (data) {
    // hopefully you are returning json. if not, return json. It's the artisan way :D
    let parsed = JSON.parse(data);

    if (parsed) {
        // build html and inject in dom
    }
});
```

Comment: `setInterval(function()
     {
    $("#example").load("list #example", function (data) {
           let parsed = JSON.parse(data);
        if (parsed) {
                jQuery("#example").html(data); 
            }
      }); }, 30000); `

I have used your code But getting Error, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Then its not json. Update your question with the exact response you are getting.

Comment: I'm not getting what you tried to say.. I wrote the above script in view and while i run the program.I see in console the following line:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Is your response valid json? That is what i need to know. Update your question with what data you are sending back from the controller

Answer (score 0):

See this is how I actually solved the problem,

I put the table inside a new div and I called the jquery .load() on that div.

Like this :

```
<div class="reloadTable">
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" id="example">

    // table data

   </table>
</div>
```

javaScript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setInterval(function() {
    $(".reloadTable").load("list  #example");                               
  }, 3000); 
</script>
```